# How to hide uinavigationbar?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have added uinavigation bar from the object library xCode(drag and drop) but I am not able to hide  it when necessary, the main thing is I not able to connect it.
Please help me, i searched every where and every one are talking about uinavigationcontroller's bar.

Comment: Increase your accepted rate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you cannot connect the outlet to your own navigation bar?.. you can. Check if your xib having correct file owner. Check out my screenshot too..

[image]

Comment: thanks your suggestion helped me out, but I am surprised that still I can't drag and create the outlet's object just like the way you suggested and I used to daily, instead I manually created and succeed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: nope, I am not talking about the navigation controller, I am talking about the 'Navigation Bar' that you drag and drop from object library. how to connect with outlet?